# How to fix namespace path after renaming a folder in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I've been practicing Caliburn.micro with mvvm pattern.. till I noticed that I have named the folder"ViewModels" ModelViews which in regards to caliburn doesn't work unless you specify the standard names, but after renaming it I noticed it that visual studio still uses the old path for example when I try to call the class LoginViewModel it automatically calls this path:

```
using Login2.ModelViews;
```

event if I try to manually type `using Login2.ViewModels;`
it doesn't recognize it.

Any suggestion would be appreciated I don't want to restart my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem by naming the namespace of the ViewModel classes
from `namespace Login2.ModelViews` to  `namespace Login2.ViewModels` hopes this will help someone in the future ^-^